# Converting Wordpress URL path into query string

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress page that accepts a query string argument:

http://x.com/page-name/?parameter=value

This works fine. The page gets the value of $_GET['parameter'] correctly.

What I want to do is make it possible to type this as a normal URL:

http://x.com/page-name/value

I need the ability to rewrite the URL so the user enters URL 2, and Wordpress gets URL 1. I am using Apache and would prefer to do this with mod_rewrite and .htaccess. Any advice?

Comment: "clean urls" is the buzz term for this. http://teamtutorials.com/web-development-tutorials/clean-url%E2%80%99s-with-wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this within WP using your theme's functions.php:

```
add_action( 'init', 'ss_permalinks' );
function ss_permalinks() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'page/remove/([^/]+)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=page&service=$matches[1]',
        'top'
);
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'ss_query_vars' );
function ss_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'removeid';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

Re-save your permalink settings once after implementing. `page` is the slug of the page to point to when the user access this URL (`domain.com/page/remove/432`), and `$matches[1]` should be the number after `remove/` in the URL. This number is accessible by the variable specified later, `$query_vars[] = 'removeid';`/ $removeid on the target page's template will be the number in the URL, if specified.