# URL rewrite query_string in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I have a taxonomy search form in wordpress and the link output is

```
http://localhost/wp/?cityid=16
```

But i want it to be rewrited as

```
http://localhost/wp/cityid/16
```

.htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630720/converting-wordpress-url-path-into-query-string) but could not implement to my case. Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteBase /wp/
RewirteRule ^wp/cityid/([0-9]+)$ ?cityid=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It gives "500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: @Adige72, try to omit RewriteBase directive.