# Redirect works but rewrite fails

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am building a price comparison site in Wordpress, using WPDataTables, php and javascript. I want to map non-existing dynamic URLs in my domain to one static URL with a question mark appended.

I tried changing my .htaccess file like so (either one or the other, never both):

```
    # BEGIN me
    RewriteEngine On    
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^cars/([^/]+)$  /cars/?$1 [L]             <== ... either this one...but fails
    RewriteRule ^cars/([^/]+)$  /cars/?$1 [L,R]           <== ... or this one, it works
    # END me
```

So the redirect functionally works but I think this is not page rank friendly. Really my site is brand new and I am not redirecting 'something old'. Google will not like it I guess.

My expectation is that if redirect works - then rewrite should also work.

I really prefer to have rewrites since they are invisible to the outside world. But this simply does not seem to work reliably.

**Questions**

1. assume I get rewrites working, I would prefer to not use ? url arguments ... if my server side php would have access to original URL and rewritten URL, then the original URL contains all info I need. But it seems this original URL is not really visible to my server side page as my `document.location.href`  already is rewritten. Still the browser address bar displays the original. Is there any way I can get access to that?
2. is it true that redirect in this case is really not the way to go? I dislike that a user sees the updated URL, there is double roundtrip as price also and it confuses google as mapping 'old' to 'new'...there was not really any 'old'.
3. what can explain that the redirect works reliably where the rewrite fails? Failing means I get 404. I am using incognito on Chrome to validate. The redirects simply work but the rewrite always fails.

Rewrites are a pain to debug really. I did use https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ to validate, but that indicates all should be OK where in practice it does not.

I have no other .htaccess files in other directories and I am on a server from hosting party so no access to apache directly.

Comment: 1. `document.location.href` looks like javascript, I thought you are using php on the server side? Now which is it? If php, then take a look at the superglobals php offers. Usually you _do_ have access to the originally requested URL, _unless_ you redirect or rewrite in multiple steps or via service borders.

Comment: 2. certainly this is not a task that should be solved by redirection. You are right there.

Comment: 3. that rewriting _should_ work, sure. If it does not for you then most likely the issue is not on protocol level, but inside your application logic. If in doubt you might want to enable rewrite logging inside your apache http server to understand what exactly is going on inside your rewriting module.

Comment: The fact that you are using a hosting provider certainly is an issue. But you need to maintain a local development setup anyway, no way around that. You should test your rules in that development setup first and only publish them once they work as expected.

Comment: _"what can explain that the redirect works reliably where the rewrite fails?"_ - WordPress uses `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to access what URL was requested - but that value will not change due to any internal rewrites, it still contains the originally requested URL. In case of an actual redirect WP sees `/cars/?foobar`, and it knows that is supposed to lead to the post with slug `cars`. With the internal rewrite only, WP still sees `/cars/foobar`, and that does not match the slug of any existing post.

Answer (score -1):

> My expectation is that if redirect works - then rewrite should also work.

Redirects cause the browser to make a second request. That triggers your server to process other rules.

What is likely happening in that you have some other rewrite rule that specifies a handler for `/cars`.  It may even be the default WordPress front controller.

I don't know of a way to make a rewrite in .htaccess that is then compatible with the WordPress front controller. You may have to write a custom WordPress theme that handles this like [Converting Wordpress URL path into query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630720/converting-wordpress-url-path-into-query-string)